# Solvable question of dee dee bar lemma

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Recently I read about the dee dee bar lemma ($\partial\bar \partial$-lemma) in Gang Tian's *Canonical metrics in Kähler Geometry*. In the middle of Page 16, the author writes that: "The following equation can be solved for $u$,
$$\bar\partial^*\theta=\bar\partial^*\bar\partial u=-g^{i\bar j}u_{\bar j i}$$
because $\int_M\bar\partial^*\theta\omega^n_g=0$."

However, I can not understand why this condition guarantees this equation to be solvable? Even I know for standard $R^n$, a form $\alpha$ is a $df$ iff $\int_{c}\alpha=0$... So what is the relationship between them?

Comment: *Dee Dee Bar* sounds like a nice place where to enjoy a drink...

Comment: Amazing discovery! @Georges Elencwajg

Comment: Dear A.T.Saaki, I hope it was completely clear that this  was a harmless wordplay and that I was in no way trying to make fun of you. Actually when I began my career in mathematics I studied the dee bar operator for quite some time and really liked it, but unfortunately I left that domain and am quite unable to answer your question.

Comment: Oh? I'm sorry, because English is not my mother tongue, I think you may misunderstand my meaning of "Amazing discoery". In my sense, it is just a joke and also thank you for your long comment...\(^o^)/   @Georges Elencwajg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think you meant to write $$\bar\partial^* \theta = \bar\partial^*\partial u = -g^{i\bar j}u_{i\bar j}$$

On Kahler manifolds the R.H.S is just the laplacian of $u$. So basically you want to solve $$-\Delta u = f$$ whenever $\int\limits_{M}f\omega^n = 0$. Here $f = \bar\partial^*\theta$ in your question. This is actually quite standard. The integral vanishing is ofcourse necessary by Stokes theorem. One transparent way to see that a solution must exist is via an eigenvalue expansion. Arguing formally (these statements can be made rigorous, consult any book on elliptic PDEs), $-\Delta$ has a discrete spectrum $0=\lambda_0\leq\lambda_1\leq\cdots\leq\lambda_k\cdots$, with corresponding eigenfunctions $\varphi_0 \equiv 1, \varphi_k$. Then $f$ has an eigenfunction expansion $$f=\mu_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu_k\varphi_k$$ $\int\limits_{M}f\omega^n = 0$ is equivalent to $\mu_0 = 0$. So then the function $$u = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu_k}{\lambda_k}\varphi_k$$ is the solution you seek. To make all this rigorous you basically need to prove that $(-\Delta + I)^{-1}$ is a compact self adjoint operator on $L^2(M,\omega)$. An excellent online reference for PDEs in geometry is Jerry Kazdan's book - http://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/japan/japan.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your re-correction and solution of this problem. Now, I understand what the key point is.